# console.log returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I'm starting with javascript and I have this problem I'm trying to return and array with the data but when I console log I get "[object Object][object Object]"

this is the data I have to work with

```
var MARKDATA = {
 "SOR": {
   "mark": [
    {
     "data": {
       "2015": 21.680000,
       "2016": 23.739999,
       "2017": 23.760000
     },
     "markName": "swimming",
     "markCode": "SWM"
   },
   {
    "data": {
       "2015": "",
       "2016": 61.55429840,
       "2017": 61.482299804
     },
     "markName": "running (time)",
     "indicatorCode": "RM"
   }
  ]
 } 
};
```

this is what I tried

```
const valuesArr= MARKDATA.SOR.mark;

let acum= '';
const showData = arr => {
 const dataArr= arr.map(value => value.data).join('') 
 acum += dataArr;
};
showData(valuesArr);

console.log(acum)
```

I want that console log returns and array with the years and the values of the object data, what I want to do is use this array to calculate with the reduce method the average of each data.

Or if someone knows a better way to get the average of the values of the object data I will apreciate it

Comment: *"I want that console log returns and array..."* Huh? You're initializing `acum` with a string (`''`), then using `+=`. The `+=` is doing string concatenation.

Comment: What do you expect `join` to do ?

Comment: You are joining an array of objects, so js calls the toString over them which returns for each one the string object Object

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is building a string, explicitly:

- You initialize `acum` with a string (`''`)
- You call `join('')` (which creates a string) on the result of the `map` operation

Since `map` is creating an array of objects, calling `join` on taht array implicitly calls `toString` on those objects. An object that doesn't have special `toString` behavior returns `"[object Object]"` in that case.

If you want an array of the `data` contents, you need to work at the array level:

```
let acum = []; // <== An array
const showData = arr => {
    const dataArr= arr.map(value => value.data); // <== No join('')
    acum.push(...dataArr); // <== Appending to the array
};
showData(valuesArr);

console.log(acum);
```

That's the minimal changes version, but there's no reason to create those temporary arrays (the return values of `map`), and there's no reason for the `showData` function. Just use a `for-of` loop. You can also include destructuring. So:

```
let acum = [];
for (const {data} of valuesArr) {
    acum.push(...data);
}

console.log(acum);
```

You can shoehorn that into a `reduce` (because you can shoehorn any array operation into a `reduce`), but it doesn't buy you anything:

```
let acum = valuesArr.reduce((a, {data}) => {
    a.push(...data);
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(acum);
```

Alternately (but this still pointlessly creates an extra array) you could use the proposed-but-still-Stage-3 [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
let acum = valueArr.map(({data}) => data).flat();

console.log(acum);
```